# preg_match_all function for getting images(with specific exitension & width-height) from url

Tags: php, html, regex, image, preg-match-all

Firstly I am fresher for PHP.
I am using follwing PHP expression for getting all images from given url.

```
@preg_match_all("<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

but this expression fetches all images with gif images also & 1KB sized images also.

I want to fetch the images with minimum width 100px & extension should be .png/.jpg

Please provide me a solution if anyone have.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any hint in the HTML about the size of the image?

Comment: A given URL or web page?

Comment: No there is no hint about the size..$homepage = @file_get_contents($_POST['url']);

Comment: So apparently you have to get all of the images URLs and use `getimagesize()` passing to it the URL of the image on the remote server in order to retrieve its size.  Perhaps it would prove more efficient to download all of the images files and analyze them locally...

Answer (score 2):

untested using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize):

```
// the domain is needed to get the width of the image
define('DOMAIN', 'http://test.com');

function checkSize($imagename) {
    $info = getimagesize(DOMAIN . $imagename[1]);
    if ($info[0] >= 100000) {
        return $imagename;
    }
}

$homepage = '<img src="test1.png"><img src="test2.gif"><img src="test3.jpg">';
// get all img-tags ending with "jpg" or "png"
preg_match_all("<img.+?src=[\"']([^\"]*\.(jpg|png))[\"'].+?>", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
// filter only images with width greater or equal 100k
$images = array_map('checkSize', $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('~<img(.*?)((src=("|\')(.*?)(jpg|png)("|\'))(.*?)(width=("|\')[0-9]{3,}("|\'))|(width=("|\')[0-9]{3,}("|\'))(.*?)(src=("|\')(.*?)(jpg|png)("|\')))(.*?)>~i',trim($string),$matches);

$yourImagesArray = $matches[0];
```

I think this should work =) at least it works here with every img tag i used for testing which have a number as value in width-attribute.

/Edit: this is better to read:

```
$src = '(src=("|\')(.*?)(jpg|png)("|\'))';
$width = '(width=("|\')[0-9]{3,}("|\'))';

preg_match_all('~<img(.*?)('.$src.'(.*?)'.$width.'|'.$width.'(.*?)'.$src.')(.*?)>~i',trim($string),$matches);

$yourImagesArray = $matches[0];
```